# jquery pushstate callback script

Tags: jquery, callback, pushstate

I use html5 history pushstate to load some blog post page.

Inside each loaded page via pushstate I have a slider (iosslider).
When I load the blog page, the slider doesn't work. I think I need to callback the iosslider script.

Here is the iosslider script to initialize it:

```
$('.iosSlider').iosSlider({
responsiveSlideContainer: true,
responsiveSlides: true,
snapToChildren: true,
desktopClickDrag: true,
keyboardControls: true,
infiniteSlider: true,
navSlideSelector: true,
autoSlide: true,
autoSlideTimer: 5000,
navNextSelector: $('.slider-next'),
navPrevSelector: $('.slider-prev'),
navSlideSelector: $('.slider-pagination .slider-page'),
onSlideChange: slideChange
});
```

How can I initialize the script when I trigger pushstate?

Sorry for my English, I'm French.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `window.onpopstate` event to call the script.

Check the doc there:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_popstate_event

**Edit**

Did you try this:

```
$(element).iosSlider('update');
```

http://iosscripts.com/iosslider/#installation-and-setup#public-methods

And do you have any errors in the console?

**Edit 2**

I doubt it's related to sync/async. The thing is that the page is not really "reloaded" when you use pushstate. My guess it that the script of the slider just stopped, and you need to start it again, but it is already instanciated you cannot just initialize it again.

Try to:

```
$(element).iosSlider('destroy');
```

and then initialize it again.

In your onpopstate function place it after this:

```
 if (event.state) {
        load_content(event.state.title, window.location.pathname, true);
        // here
```

**Edit 3**

Use:

```
$(window).load(function () { 
     // initialize
});
```

Be aware that onload will be triggered before onpopstate.

Comment: Show me the sample of code where you try that. And it's "doesn't"* for the third person by the way ;)

Comment: You can see my pushstate script here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658895/html5-pushstate-and-seo-link , without any callback script. The best way is to callback inside my load_content function but it doesn't works. I think it's because the asynchronous task...

Comment: The update function not work correctly. If I put the script to initialize isoslider inside windows resize it works on browser resize (it doesn't works with update function)... I need to be sure that all content is loaded before to callback iosslider...

Comment: It doesn't work with your updated answer. But I near sure that the best way is to call back in my load_content function...

Comment: It's not working. But I find the solution. In my load_content function, I put my iosslider initialization function at the end with a setTimeout in order to be sure that the iosslider container exist before to try do update it... It works but I'm sure there is a better solution....

Comment: Ye the solution you are seeking is .load(), it's checking if everything is loaded. But the problem is that i'm not quite sure it it's triggered for history manipulation.

Comment: Yes, I try it into pushstate but it's not working. With the setTimeout it works great. So it's ok finally. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, too bad that we couldnt find a better solution than a timeout, wich is  gonna get bugged for slow conn.

Comment: Ahhh !! I know why .load() doesnt work. It is because onpopstate is triggered after onload !! So placing it there won't work indeed. Just put your initilization in .load() instead of .ready or wherever you call.

Comment: ok. But if I put my init function for the slider in a load(), nothing happen. I think it's impossible to call a load after a page is load with pushstate. I think for slow connection it will not be a problem. The div container are created wery fastly... My problem was because of some settime out animation before my initialization. Thank you for your help.